# How to add the position of onClick event to the hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

My code is here:

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import React, { useState } from 'react';


    export default function App() {
      const [newLat, setNewLat] = useState(null);
      const [newLng, setNewLng] = useState(null);
    
    <MapContainer 
        center={[49.1951, 16.6068]} 
        zoom={defaultZoom} 
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        eventHandlers={{
              click:(event)=>{
              setNewLat(event.latlng.lat());
              setNewLng(event.latlng.long());
              console.log(newLat, newLng);
              },
        }}>
    <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
      </MapContainer>
```

The problem is that nothing happens when I click on the map, what is my mistake?
Thank you!

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You are not using `newLat` or `newLng` anywhere so the state updates will not have any visual impact on how your app renders. It always renders the same map with the same static values no matter which values your states hold. Also it should probably not be named `new...` but you should intitialize your state with initial values for `lat` and `lng` and use the state values to initialize your `MapContainer`.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64937948/adding-onclick-function-to-a-mapcontainer-from-react-leaflet-in-typescript-f help you?

Comment: I have added here just a simplified version of my code, I will use newLat and newLng in another component

Comment: I can't find any documentation about an `eventHandlers` prop on the `MapContainer` component. Where did you take the information from that event handlers can be provided through that prop? Is this using an older version of `react-leaflet`?

Comment: Thank you, I have used this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64937948/adding-onclick-function-to-a-mapcontainer-from-react-leaflet-in-typescript-f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react-leaflet v3` at least the following options could be considered to attach `click` event handler on map (also covered in [official documentation](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/ea129b4f9824d5c16d095e4f22c75b7479306eaf/packages/website/docs/api-map.md#mapconsumer)):

Option 1: via [`useMapEvents` hook](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#usemapevents)

```
function MyMap() {
  const [loc, setLoc] = useState(null);
  const map = useMapEvents({
    click: (e) => {
      setLoc(e.latlng);
      console.log(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng);
    },
 
  })
  return null
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={[49.1951, 16.6068]}
      zoom={defaultZoom}
      scrollWheelZoom={false}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      ></TileLayer>
      <MyMap />
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

Option 2: via [`useMapEvent` hook](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#usemapevent)

> The difference with option 1, the later one supports attaching a *single*
> event handler to the map instance

```
function MyMap() {
  const [loc, setLoc] = useState(null);
  const map = useMapEvent('click', (e) => {
      setLoc(e.latlng);
      console.log(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng);
  })
  return null
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={[49.1951, 16.6068]}
      zoom={defaultZoom}
      scrollWheelZoom={false}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      ></TileLayer>
      <MyMap />
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

Option 3: via [`MapConsumer` component](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/ea129b4f9824d5c16d095e4f22c75b7479306eaf/packages/website/docs/api-map.md#mapconsumer):

```
function Map() {
  const [loc, setLoc] = useState(null);
  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={[49.1951, 16.6068]}
      zoom={defaultZoom}
      scrollWheelZoom={false}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      ></TileLayer>
      <MapConsumer>
        {(map) => {
          map.on("click", (e) => {
            setLoc(e.latlng);
            console.log(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng);
          });

          return null;
        }}
      </MapConsumer>
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

Option 4: using [`useMap` hook](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#usemap)

```
function MyMap() {
  const [loc, setLoc] = useState(null);
  const map = useMap();
  map.on("click", (e) => {
     setLoc(e.latlng);
     console.log(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng);
  });
  return null
}

function App() {
  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={[49.1951, 16.6068]}
      zoom={defaultZoom}
      scrollWheelZoom={false}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      ></TileLayer>
      <MyMap />
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

Option 5: event gets attached to underlying map instance once map is created (`whenCreated`):

```
function Map() {
  const [loc, setLoc] = useState(null);


  function hanleMapCreated(map){
    map.on("click", (e) => {
       setLoc(e.latlng);
       console.log(e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng);
    });
  }

  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={[49.1951, 16.6068]}
      zoom={defaultZoom}
      scrollWheelZoom={false}
      whenCreated={hanleMapCreated}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      ></TileLayer>
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```