# How to handle events in react-leaflet v3 on a dataset?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-leaflet

I've been using react-leaflet v3 in order to map the hospitals in a given radius. I have a component that retrieve that information from an endpoint, that's the **Hospitals** component in the following code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import Hospitals from "./Hospitals";

export default class MyMap extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);    
    this.state = {
      id: 0,
      lat: -23.550519,
      lng: -46.633309,
      zoom: 12
    };
  }

  render() {
    const position = [this.state.lat, this.state.lng];
    return (
      <MapContainer center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
        <Hospitals />
        <TileLayer
          attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
      </MapContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

So, that worked like a charm!
[image]

The dataset is retrieved and markers are displayed over the map and every marker corresponds to a hospital in the aforementioned dataset.

Now, I want to apply events on each of those markers to display information about each of them, i.e., the name, address and number of ICUs available per hospital.

How can I be able to apply events over a dataset in the MapContainer? The [documentation](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#usemap) isn't super exhaustive about that and I'm getting errors trying to match the few examples I've googled so far.

I've found this [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64937948/adding-onclick-function-to-a-mapcontainer-from-react-leaflet-in-typescript-f) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66671481/how-to-add-the-position-of-onclick-event-to-the-hook), but when I try to apply the same logic I found errors such as:

> React Hook "useMap" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks
> must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook
> function

I've created a component for the handling of events on the map. Then I hooked that component to the MapContainer. Obviously it didn't work because it is not working on the dataset.

**EDIT:** Adding Hospitals' component code

```js
import React from "react";
import { GeoJSON } from "react-leaflet";
const overpass = require("query-overpass");

export default class Hospitals extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     geojson: undefined,
     map: undefined,
     setMap: undefined
   };
 }

 render() {
   return this.state.geojson ? <GeoJSON data={this.state.geojson} /> : null;
 }

 componentDidMount() {
   const query = `[out:json];(way[healthcare~"^(hospital|clinic)$"](around:50000, -23.550519, -46.633309);\
                              relation[healthcare~"^(hospital|clinic)$"](around:50000, -23.550519, -46.633309););\
                              out center;>;out skel qt;`;
   const options = {
     flatProperties: true
   };
   overpass(query, this.dataHandler, options);
 }

 dataHandler = (error, osmData) => {
   if (!error && osmData.features !== undefined) {
     this.setState({ geojson: osmData });
   }
 };

}
```

This component uses query-overpass library in order to retrieve the information available in OpenStreetMaps. In this particular case, the information of healthcare centers in geojson format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to consider is to bind a popup to marker click via [`Marker.bindPopup`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html) method. In terms of `react-leaflet` library, `GeoJSON` component exposes `onEachFeature` event which gets called on each feature and where popup could be initialized.

Here is a modified `Hospitals` component which demonstrates how to bind a popup to marker click:

```
class Hospitals extends React.Component {
  handleEachFeature(feature, layer) {    
    const popupContent = feature.properties.hospitalDesc; //it is assumed  GeoJSON feature contains hospitalDesc property
    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GeoJSON data={hostpitalData} onEachFeature={this.handleEachFeature} />
    );
  }
}
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bs7bjr) for your reference

Comment: Thanks, now I see I have to attach the events to the GeoJSON object